# Unable to Retrieve cookies when request is called using Spring RestTemplate

Tags: spring, rest, http, session, resttemplate

I have two web applications. There is a HttpSession at second application and first application knows the sessionid of it.

I am making a request from First application to second application using RestTemplate by adding its session id to headers.

When the request is received at the second application, I am trying to read all its cookies from request. But, I only see the JSESSIONID cookie and don't get all the cookies that I set previously.

Suppose, I access the same url on the browser manually, I see all those cookies retrieved.

Request made in First application:

```
String sessionId = "6iuvgwy5ceqzwlxh646qo0ms";//SessionId of second application
String url = "http://example.com/data/retrieve";
HttpHeaders requestHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
requestHeaders.add("Cookie", "JSESSIONID=" + sessionId);
HttpEntity<String> requestEntity = new HttpEntity<String>(null, requestHeaders);
ResponseEntity<String> responseEntity = restTemplate.exchange(url, 
HttpMethod.GET, requestEntity, String.class);
```

If this can't be done using Spring RestTemplate, please suggest me if there is any other way of doing it.

Comment: In your code, I can only see one Cookie being set (JSESSIONID). Where are the others?

Comment: Roman, In App2, as I said I have a session(I use App2 in the same browser in another tab, I login to it and create a cookie(token) from java after I login). From App1, I access the one of the resource(http://example.com/data/retrieve) of App2 with its jsessionid from App1, when the request reaches at App2, since i have the jsessionid in the headers it is retrieving the session, but not all the cookies of the session which I created after I login.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no session cookie. Cookie is just a header. 
You lind of reset the header to have only `JSESSIONID`.

To fix it change the logic a bit

You somehow get the session id (I guess from some request). Get not only the session but all the rest cookie as well and add them to the requestHeaders when you call the `restTemplate`.

Comment: StanislavL, Thanks, I am trying to do the same.